# Toggleable / Dynamic Pils show content after the line Bootstrap 3

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Good afternoon)
Faced with the problem of adaptation Toggleable / Dynamic Pils in bootstrap 3, I want to do on mobile phones li were 100% of the width, but the content is shown immediately after them, not after all the elements. How can I fix it? 
Thank you in advance

Or advise, another tool for this task)

```
<div class="container">
<h2>Dynamic Pills</h2>
<ul class="nav nav-pills">
  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">Home</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="tab-content">
<div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
  <h3>HOME</h3>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
</div>
<div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu 1</h3>
  <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
</div>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu 2</h3>
  <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
</div>
<div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
  <h3>Menu 3</h3>
  <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
</div>
```

[image: What I mean]

Comment: The feature you want to implement on mobile is called "collapse/accordion" & on desktop you want "dynamic pills". Unfortunately the HTML structuring for both is completely different from each other to get it working. For collapse you need to **move the "menu" items inside the `<ul>` next to its respective `<li>`for mobile**. This would involve dirty javascript code. Are you fine with that ?

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I wouldn't like dirty code :)
you think is easier to use a different approach?

Comment: Frankly speaking according to me the best solution would be to create an accordion & on mobile show it(hiding the dynamic pills) & vice-versa on desktop

Comment: Yes a different & a better approach would be as I mentioned above. Since your requirement is weird I guess we will have to go towards weird solutions as well :)

Comment: @NikhilNanjappa I was worried at how it then write functional :)
Did as advised, on small screens show an accordion. Thank you )